# Update HTML Content from Controller (After html page shown)

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework

I'm trying to update an HTML Page after shown. 
The purpose is to show an empty table first and insert a new row every time that I receive a response of asynchronous requests executed in parallel.

Below the way to show my html page.

```
    .....

    //This method allows to launch for each user a request
    launchRequests(users, new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void update(Status status) {
            //TODO Update HTML CONTENT by inserting a row in created table
        }
    });

    return ok(views.html.test.render());
```

I already try to make requests with ajax but the way to handle error is not the same.

**Is there a way to update current HTML content in update callback?**

Comment: Maybe what you want is [Comet](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaComet) so that every new status update you will get a content chunk. Or maybe [WebSockets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets) and emit new messages to the client. Of course, this requires work on both server and client sides. Some examples: https://github.com/playframework/play-java-streaming-example and https://github.com/playframework/play-java-websocket-example

Comment: This is not something you can do that way. This is not the way how Web was designed to be used and thus not the way web-browsers work. By default a web-browser has no persistent connection to the server that server can send something back after the main bunch of data. The old-fashion work-around is to use AJAX to regularly ask from the page the server for available updates. Other more modern workarounds are noted in the previous comment by  marcospereira.